# Prompt for general iOS Location Services

Tags: ios, objective-c, location-services

I would like to  ask the user to enable the general Locations Services (not the app specific Location Services) if as a whole they never get prompted to enable it for the app.

Is there a way to prompt the user to turn on Location Services as a whole every time they open the app and it is disabled?

Code found in other threads, but it is App specific, not general Location Services:

```
if(![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
    NSLog(@"Location Services is OFF GLOBALLY");

    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:NSLocalizedString( @"Location Services", @"" ) message:NSLocalizedString( @"Please Set Location Services to On and Restart App\n\nSettings->Privacy->Location Services", @"" ) preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString( @"OK", @"" ) style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];

    [alertController addAction:okAction];

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];


}
else if([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
    NSLog(@"Location Services is Never for App");

    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:NSLocalizedString( @"App Needs Location Services", @"" ) message:NSLocalizedString( @"Please Set Location Services to Always for App", @"" ) preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *settingsAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString( @"Settings", @"" ) style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];  

    [alertController addAction:settingsAction];

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: Why? You only need the app specific setting.

Comment: Perhaps if you share what you're really trying to accomplish we can help better, as there is no reason to prompt the user to enable Location Services entirely if your app isn't going to ask for permission to use it.

Comment: You can check the value of `CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled` and display an alert if location services are disabled, but there is no way to open the location services preferences directly.

Comment: I have run in to a bunch of people that will turn on location services for a moment, and then turn it off. This is not the apps settings, but the global settings. Currently my app doesn't not prompt if the general location service is off, it will only prompt if it is on and the apps location services setting off.  Hope that clarifies a bit.

Comment: updated original post with more code

Answer (score 1):

In your `info.plist` file, you'll want to include one of the following lines:

If it's always in use, then add this entry to `info.plist`:

```
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
```

The string associated with that entry should be the message you want displayed: `Would you like to enable continual location monitoring even when this app is not in use?"

...or...

You could do `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and a message along the lines of, "Would you like to enable location monitoring only when this app is in use?"

[Here's documentation covering this topic](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html)